# Sequence format in Openerp

Tags: python, xml, odoo

In openerp sequences we can insert current year with century as suffix or prefix as following:

```
    /%(year)s
```

I need to get the fiscal year as suffix in the sequence. Is there any possible way?

for eg: PO/0001/2012-2013

Comment: Hi @Pravith Are you find any solution for the above question ?.If you find the solution please post your answer Thanks..

Comment: if you are getting answer. please post here

Answer (score 2):

When you create the sequence, you can add this function to return value with sequence.

You could try this function to find the fiscal year:

```
  def finyear(self):
    today=date.today()
    months=today.month
    if months<=3:
        return '%d-%d'%(today.year-1,today.year)
    return '%d-%d'%(today.year,today.year+1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to generate the current year you can do so with the datetime module like so

```
import datetime
print datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now(), '%Y')
```

Which will give you '2012'. You can read more on the module in the [datetime docs](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html)

EDIT:
Something more along these lines then ?

```
import datetime

def get_fiscal_year(start_month=3):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    if now.month >= start_month:
        return '%d-%d' % (now.year, now.year + 1)
    return '%d-%d' % (now.year - 1, now.year)
```

Comment: no sir i have gt the current year my requirement is i want the fiscal year eg:2012-2013 and in the next fiscal year it should automaticaly change to 2013-2014 etc

Comment: you cant use the above function..bcoz some times fiscal year name will be like "Fiscal Year 2012" or just '2012'

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any way to do this using only the suffix or prefix field of a sequence. However, you probably could do it by writing a module that extends the `ir_sequence` class. The current class [provides a dictionary](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-server/trunk/view/4168/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_sequence.py#L173) with values that you can use in a sequence prefix or suffix.

```
def _interpolation_dict(self):
    t = time.localtime() # Actually, the server is always in UTC.
    return {
        'year': time.strftime('%Y', t),
        'month': time.strftime('%m', t),
        'day': time.strftime('%d', t),
        'y': time.strftime('%y', t),
        'doy': time.strftime('%j', t),
        'woy': time.strftime('%W', t),
        'weekday': time.strftime('%w', t),
        'h24': time.strftime('%H', t),
        'h12': time.strftime('%I', t),
        'min': time.strftime('%M', t),
        'sec': time.strftime('%S', t),
    }
```

If you were to override that with a version that looks up the [current fiscal year](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-addons/trunk/view/6825/account/account.py#L946) and adds another entry, it would probably do what you want.

It would probably be wise to measure performance in some places that need to generate a bunch of sequence numbers, since a database lookup is a lot slower than checking the system time. You might want to cache the fiscal year for a while.

Answer (score 0):

prefixing fiscal year and resetting the sequence code for every fiscal year can be done like below. 
Introduce a new sequence attribute **%(fiscal_year)s**. 
Here is how to do it. Inherit  ir_sequence and override the methods _interpolation_dict, and _next

added a new column fiscal_year_name. This column is set a value fiscal year name for every _next call and resets when fiscal year name changes.

sequence xml

```
<record id="seq_cust_invoice_no" model="ir.sequence">
    <field name="name">Customer Invoice No.</field>
    <field name="code">cust_invoice_no</field>
    <field name="prefix">%(fiscal_year)s/</field>
            <field name="padding">4</field>
            <field name="number_increment">1</field>
        </record>
```

Code below:

class ir_sequence(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'ir.sequence'

```
_columns = {
    'fiscal_year_name': fields.char('Created Fiscal year', size=64, help="Created Fiscal year"),
}

def _interpolation_dict(self, cr, uid, fy):
    res = super(ir_sequence, self)._interpolation_dict()        
    res['fiscal_year'] = fy.name
    return res

def _next(self, cr, uid, seq_ids, context=None):
    if not seq_ids:
        return False
    if context is None:
        context = {}
    company_id = self.pool.get('res.users').browse(cr, uid, uid).company_id.id
    fiscal_year_id = self.pool.get('account.fiscalyear').search(cr, uid, [('state','=','draft'), ('company_id', '=', company_id)])
    fy = self.pool.get('account.fiscalyear').browse(cr, uid, fiscal_year_id)[0]

    # Honoring the changes for ir_sequence.py override in accounts
    sequence_ids = seq_ids
    for seq in self.browse(cr, uid, seq_ids, context):
        for line in seq.fiscal_ids:
            if line.fiscalyear_id.id == context.get('fiscalyear_id'):
                sequence_ids = [line.sequence_id.id]
                break

    force_company = context.get('force_company')
    if not force_company:
        force_company = self.pool.get('res.users').browse(cr, uid, uid).company_id.id

    sequences = self.read(cr, uid, sequence_ids, ['name','company_id','implementation','number_next','prefix','suffix','padding', 'fiscal_year_name'])
    preferred_sequences = [s for s in sequences if s['company_id'] and s['company_id'][0] == force_company ]
    seq = preferred_sequences[0] if preferred_sequences else sequences[0]
    if seq['implementation'] == 'standard':
        if seq['prefix'] == '%(fiscal_year)s/':
            if not seq['fiscal_year_name'] or fy.name != seq['fiscal_year_name']:
                cr.execute("SELECT setval('ir_sequence_%03d', 1, true)" % seq['id'])
                seq['number_next'] = cr.fetchone()
            else:
                cr.execute("SELECT nextval('ir_sequence_%03d')" % seq['id'])
                seq['number_next'] = cr.fetchone()
        else:
            cr.execute("SELECT nextval('ir_sequence_%03d')" % seq['id'])
            seq['number_next'] = cr.fetchone()
    else:
        cr.execute("SELECT number_next FROM ir_sequence WHERE id=%s FOR UPDATE NOWAIT", (seq['id'],))
        cr.execute("UPDATE ir_sequence SET number_next=number_next+number_increment WHERE id=%s ", (seq['id'],))
    d = self._interpolation_dict(cr, uid, fy)
    try:
        interpolated_prefix = self._interpolate(seq['prefix'], d)
        interpolated_suffix = self._interpolate(seq['suffix'], d)
    except ValueError:
        raise osv.except_osv(_('Warning'), _('Invalid prefix or suffix for sequence \'%s\'') % (seq.get('name')))

    self.write(cr, uid, sequence_ids, {'fiscal_year_name': fy.name}, context=context)

    return interpolated_prefix + '%%0%sd' % seq['padding'] % seq['number_next'] + interpolated_suffix
```

ir_sequence()